# how to implement join query in spring jdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

Here i have a join query called

```
SELECT um.USER_ID, um.USERNAME, um.PASSWORD,  um.AGENCIA,  
       um.EMAIL, um.GRABADO_POR,  um.MOBILENUMBER,  
       um.USER_STATUS,  um.ZONE,  um.NAME, 
       um.USER_TYPE,  urmm.USERROLEMAPPING_ID, 
       r.ROLE_ID,  r.ROLE_NAME,  r.PRIORITY,  
       rcmm.COMPONENT_ID,  am.ACTION_ID,  am.ACTION_NMAE,  
       cm.COMPONENTID,  cm.COMPONENTNAME,  cm.COMPONENTIDENTIFICATION, 
       cm.COMPONENTSTATE 
FROM USER_MASTER um,  role r, USER_ROLE_MAPPING_MASTER urmm, 
     ACTION_MASTER am, ROLE_COMPONENT_MAPPING_MASTER rcmm, 
     ACTION_COMPONENT_MAPPINGMASTER acm,COMPONENT_MASTER cm 
WHERE upper(um.USERNAME) = upper(?) AND um.USER_ID = urmm.USER_ID AND 
      urmm.ROLE_ID = r.ROLE_ID AND r.ROLE_ID = rcmm.ROLE_ID AND
      urmm.ROLE_ID = rcmm.ROLE_ID AND 
      acm.ACTION_ID = am.ACTION_ID AND 
      rcmm.COMPONENT_NAME = acm.COMPONENT_NAME AND 
      acm.COMPONENT_NAME=cm.COMPONENTNAME(+)
```

i have to set that query into my beans, is it possible with row mapper or is there any way to implement. here i am posting my practiced code is is recomended? if it is not correct then give me suggetions.

**In DAOImpl**

```
@Override
    public List<User> getUserTest(String username) {

final List<User> userList=new ArrayList<User>();

        String query="SELECT um.USER_ID, um.USERNAME, um.PASSWORD,  um.AGENCIA,  um.EMAIL, um.GRABADO_POR,  um.MOBILENUMBER,  um.USER_STATUS,  um.ZONE,  um.NAME, um.USER_TYPE,  urmm.USERROLEMAPPING_ID,  r.ROLE_ID,  r.ROLE_NAME,  r.PRIORITY,  rcmm.COMPONENT_ID,  am.ACTION_ID,  am.ACTION_NMAE,  cm.COMPONENTID,  cm.COMPONENTNAME,  cm.COMPONENTIDENTIFICATION, cm.COMPONENTSTATE FROM USER_MASTER um,  role r, USER_ROLE_MAPPING_MASTER urmm, ACTION_MASTER am, ROLE_COMPONENT_MAPPING_MASTER rcmm, ACTION_COMPONENT_MAPPINGMASTER acm,COMPONENT_MASTER cm WHERE upper(um.USERNAME)=upper(?) AND um.USER_ID          =urmm.USER_ID AND urmm.ROLE_ID        =r.ROLE_ID AND r.ROLE_ID           =rcmm.ROLE_ID AND urmm.ROLE_ID        =rcmm.ROLE_ID AND acm.ACTION_ID       =am.ACTION_ID AND rcmm.COMPONENT_NAME =acm.COMPONENT_NAME AND acm.COMPONENT_NAME=cm.COMPONENTNAME(+)";
        System.out.println("in dao");

        try{
        List<Object> users  = getJdbcTemplate().query(query, new Object[] { username },
                new RowMapper<Object>(){

                    @Override
                    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1)
                            throws SQLException {

                        User user=new User();
                        user.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                        user.setUsername(rs.getString(2));
                        user.setPassword(rs.getString(3));
                        user.setAgencia(rs.getString(4));
                        user.setEmail(rs.getString(5));
                        user.setGrabadoPor(rs.getString(6));
                        user.setMobileNumber(rs.getString(7));
                        user.setUserStatus(rs.getString(8));
                        user.setZone(rs.getString(9));
                        user.setName(rs.getString(10));
                        user.setUserType(rs.getString(11));

                        Set<UserRole> urole=user.getUserRoles();
                         if(urole == null){
                             urole = new HashSet<UserRole>();
                         }

                         UserRole userRole=new UserRole();
                         userRole.setId(rs.getInt(12));
                        // System.out.println("id is user role"+user.getId());
                         userRole.setUser(user);

                         Role role=userRole.getRole();

                         if(role == null){
                             role = new Role();
                            }

                         role.setRoleId(rs.getInt(13));
                         role.setRoleName(rs.getString(14));
                         role.setPriority(rs.getInt(15));
                         role.setUserRoles(urole);
                         Set<RoleAction> roleAction=role.getRoleActions();

                         if(roleAction == null){
                             roleAction = new HashSet<RoleAction>();
                            }

                         RoleAction roleaction=new RoleAction();
                         roleaction.setId(rs.getInt(16));
                         roleaction.setRole(role);

                        Action action= roleaction.getAction();

                         if(action == null){
                             action = new Action();
                            }

                        action.setActionId(rs.getInt(17));
                        action.setActionName(rs.getString(18));
                        Set<CustomizableMenus> custmenusSet=action.getCustomizablemenu();

                         if(custmenusSet == null){
                             custmenusSet = new HashSet<CustomizableMenus>();
                         }

                         CustomizableMenus custmenus=new CustomizableMenus();

                         custmenus.setComponentId(rs.getInt(19));
                         custmenus.setComponentName(rs.getString(20));
                         custmenus.setComponentIdentification(rs.getString(21));
                         custmenus.setComponentState(rs.getString(22));
                         custmenusSet.add(custmenus);
                         action.setCustomizablemenu(custmenusSet);

                        System.out.println("action id and name is "+rs.getInt(17)+" "+rs.getString(18));
                        action.setRoleActions(roleAction);

                        roleaction.setAction(action);
                        roleAction.add(roleaction);
                        role.setRoleActions(roleAction);
                        userRole.setRole(role);
                        urole.add(userRole);
                        user.setUserRoles(urole);
                        userList.add(user);

                         System.out.println("cust menus in db custid "+ custmenus.getComponentId()+"component name is "+custmenus.getComponentName()+"identification "+custmenus.getComponentIdentification());

                        return user;
                    }

        });

        if (userList.size()>0) {

            System.out.println("the list is "+ userList);

            return userList;

        }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return null;
    }
```

**user.java**

```
private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private String reTypeMobileNumber;
    private String status;
    private String userType;
    private String userDescription;
    private String grabadoPor;
    private String userStatus;
    private String zone;
    private String agencia;
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);
```

**UserRole.java**

```
public class UserRole implements Serializable{
    private Integer id;
    private User user;
    private Role role;
```

**Role.java**

```
public class Role implements Serializable{

    private Integer roleId;
    private String roleName;
    private Integer priority;
    private String roleType;
    private String roleDescription;
    private String roledentification;
    private String grabadoPor;
    private Date fechaDeCreacion;
    private Date fechaDeModificada;


    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);
    private Set<RoleAction> roleActions = new HashSet<RoleAction>(0);
```

**RoleAction.java**

```
public class RoleAction implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private Role role;
    private Action action;
```

**Action.java**

```
public class Action implements Serializable{

    private Integer actionId;
    private String actionName;
    private String actionType;
    private String url;
    private Date fechaDeCreacion;
    private Date fechaDeModificada;
    private Set<RoleAction> roleActions = new HashSet<RoleAction>(0);
    private Set<CustomizableMenus> customizablemenu=new HashSet<CustomizableMenus>(0);
```

**CustomizableMenus.java**

```
public class CustomizableMenus implements Serializable{


    private Integer componentId;
    private String componentName;
    private String componentIdentification;
    //private String componentType;
    private String componentState;
```

is it possible to reduce the amount of code.And with hibernate it is returning all the user related roles and roles related actions and action related custom menus in only one user object so i am returning list.get(0). here my join query returning how many actions he is having that many records it is returning. so i am getting morethan one user object i am getting, so if i send list of users to front end it is returning that last record which query returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy. You can do as follows. 
Create one *View Object class* named **UserActionVO.java** and create one mapper class for it named **UserActionVOMapper.java** as follows.

**UserActionVO.java**

```
public class UserActionVO {
    private int userId;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String agencia;
    private String email;
    private String grabadoPor;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private String userStatus;
    private String zone;
    private String name;
    private String userType;
    private int userRoleMappingId;
    private int roleId;
    private String roleName;
    private int priority;
    private int roleActionId;
    private String roleActionName;
    private int componentId;
    private String componentName;
    private String componentIdentification;
    private String componentState;
    /**
     * @return the userId
     */
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    /**
     * @param userId the userId to set
     */
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the userName
     */
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    /**
     * @param userName the userName to set
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    /**
     * @return the agencia
     */
    public String getAgencia() {
        return agencia;
    }
    /**
     * @param agencia the agencia to set
     */
    public void setAgencia(String agencia) {
        this.agencia = agencia;
    }
    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    /**
     * @return the grabadoPor
     */
    public String getGrabadoPor() {
        return grabadoPor;
    }
    /**
     * @param grabadoPor the grabadoPor to set
     */
    public void setGrabadoPor(String grabadoPor) {
        this.grabadoPor = grabadoPor;
    }
    /**
     * @return the mobileNumber
     */
    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @param mobileNumber the mobileNumber to set
     */
    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @return the userStatus
     */
    public String getUserStatus() {
        return userStatus;
    }
    /**
     * @param userStatus the userStatus to set
     */
    public void setUserStatus(String userStatus) {
        this.userStatus = userStatus;
    }
    /**
     * @return the zone
     */
    public String getZone() {
        return zone;
    }
    /**
     * @param zone the zone to set
     */
    public void setZone(String zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }
    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    /**
     * @return the userType
     */
    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }
    /**
     * @param userType the userType to set
     */
    public void setUserType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }
    /**
     * @return the userRoleMappingId
     */
    public int getUserRoleMappingId() {
        return userRoleMappingId;
    }
    /**
     * @param userRoleMappingId the userRoleMappingId to set
     */
    public void setUserRoleMappingId(int userRoleMappingId) {
        this.userRoleMappingId = userRoleMappingId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the roleId
     */
    public int getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }
    /**
     * @param roleId the roleId to set
     */
    public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the roleName
     */
    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }
    /**
     * @param roleName the roleName to set
     */
    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the priority
     */
    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
    /**
     * @param priority the priority to set
     */
    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }
    /**
     * @return the roleActionId
     */
    public int getRoleActionId() {
        return roleActionId;
    }
    /**
     * @param roleActionId the roleActionId to set
     */
    public void setRoleActionId(int roleActionId) {
        this.roleActionId = roleActionId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the roleActionName
     */
    public String getRoleActionName() {
        return roleActionName;
    }
    /**
     * @param roleActionName the roleActionName to set
     */
    public void setRoleActionName(String roleActionName) {
        this.roleActionName = roleActionName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the componentId
     */
    public int getComponentId() {
        return componentId;
    }
    /**
     * @param componentId the componentId to set
     */
    public void setComponentId(int componentId) {
        this.componentId = componentId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the componentName
     */
    public String getComponentName() {
        return componentName;
    }
    /**
     * @param componentName the componentName to set
     */
    public void setComponentName(String componentName) {
        this.componentName = componentName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the componentIdentification
     */
    public String getComponentIdentification() {
        return componentIdentification;
    }
    /**
     * @param componentIdentification the componentIdentification to set
     */
    public void setComponentIdentification(String componentIdentification) {
        this.componentIdentification = componentIdentification;
    }
    /**
     * @return the componentState
     */
    public String getComponentState() {
        return componentState;
    }
    /**
     * @param componentState the componentState to set
     */
    public void setComponentState(String componentState) {
        this.componentState = componentState;
    }

}
```

**UserActionVOMapper.java**

```
public class UserActionVOMapper implements RowMapper<UserActionVO>(){
    @Override  
    public UserActionVO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException {  
        UserActionVO userActionVO = new UserActionVO();  
        userActionVO.setUserId(rs.getString("USER_ID"));
        userActionVO.setUserName(rs.getString("USERNAME"));
        userActionVO.setPassword(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
        userActionVO.setAgencia(rs.getString("AGENCIA"));
        userActionVO.setEmail(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
        userActionVO.setGrabadoPor(rs.getString("GRABADO_POR"));
        userActionVO.setMobileNumber(rs.getString("MOBILENUMBER"));
        userActionVO.setUserStatus(rs.getString("USER_STATUS"));
        userActionVO.setZone(rs.getString("ZONE"));
        userActionVO.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
        userActionVO.setUserType(rs.getString("USER_TYPE")); 
        userActionVO.setUserRoleMappingId(rs.getInt("USERROLEMAPPING_ID"));
        userActionVO.setRoleId(rs.getInt("ROLE_ID"));
        userActionVO.setRoleName(rs.getString("ROLE_NAME"));
        userActionVO.setPriority(rs.getInt("PRIORITY"));
        userActionVO.setRoleActionId(rs.getInt("COMPONENT_ID"));
        userActionVO.setActionId(rs.getInt("ACTION_ID"));
        userActionVO.setActionName(rs.getString("ACTION_NMAE"));
        userActionVO.setComponentId(rs.getInt("COMPONENTID"));
        userActionVO.setComponentName(rs.getString("COMPONENTNAME"));
        userActionVO.setComponentIdentification(rs.getString("COMPONENTIDENTIFICATION"));
        userActionVO.setComponentState(rs.getString("COMPONENTSTATE"));
        return userActionVO;  
    }
}
```

Now use it in your code as follows, return the **UserActionVO POJO list** instead of **list of User POJOs**:

```
@Override
public List<UserActionVO> getUserTest(String username) {

    final List<UserActionVO> userActionVOs = null;

    String query="SELECT um.USER_ID, um.USERNAME, um.PASSWORD,  um.AGENCIA,  um.EMAIL, um.GRABADO_POR,  um.MOBILENUMBER,  um.USER_STATUS,  um.ZONE,  um.NAME, um.USER_TYPE,  urmm.USERROLEMAPPING_ID,  r.ROLE_ID,  r.ROLE_NAME,  r.PRIORITY,  rcmm.COMPONENT_ID,  am.ACTION_ID,  am.ACTION_NMAE,  cm.COMPONENTID,  cm.COMPONENTNAME,  cm.COMPONENTIDENTIFICATION, cm.COMPONENTSTATE FROM USER_MASTER um,  role r, USER_ROLE_MAPPING_MASTER urmm, ACTION_MASTER am, ROLE_COMPONENT_MAPPING_MASTER rcmm, ACTION_COMPONENT_MAPPINGMASTER acm,COMPONENT_MASTER cm WHERE upper(um.USERNAME)=upper(?) AND um.USER_ID          =urmm.USER_ID AND urmm.ROLE_ID        =r.ROLE_ID AND r.ROLE_ID           =rcmm.ROLE_ID AND urmm.ROLE_ID        =rcmm.ROLE_ID AND acm.ACTION_ID       =am.ACTION_ID AND rcmm.COMPONENT_NAME =acm.COMPONENT_NAME AND acm.COMPONENT_NAME=cm.COMPONENTNAME(+)";
    System.out.println("in dao");

    try{
        userActionVOs  = getJdbcTemplate().query(query, new Object[] { username }, new UserActionVOMapper());

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return userList;
}
```

**Easy !!! Right !!**

Let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: finally i want to set those values in the user class, other wise user will not logged in.i posted my beans please check it.

Comment: You have all the values in **UserActionVO** so now you can set and convert it to User List in service layer(better approach) or here itself. You have already did that in mapper. You just have to get the respective value from your **UserActionVO**  and set it to where ever you need.

Comment: @mike- If you wish you can mark this as an answer if this satisfies your requirement so it may help others too.